# Identifying uniqueness of a series through arithmetic operations

Tags: algorithms, arithmetic

Let's say I have a set of integers permutated to create different series.  Let's say $1$ through $6$.  Each series of length $N$.  Say $N =64$.

$6^{64}$ is ~ $6\times10^{49}$ possibilities.

If I randomly generate a series to evaluate, how can I first check I haven't already evaluated it without storing the complete series?

For example, could I do a few simple arithmetic operations in the new series to compare with past series, assessing uniqueness?  (Storing just the metrics from the old series, not the actual old series.)

Like sum(New) and sum(diff(new)) and product(New) NOT = sum(Old) and sum(diff(Old)) and product(Old)

Answer (score 1):

This "checksum" approach does not work perfectly.

I you compress the $64$ digits ($n$ possibilities) in a single integer $\in [1,m]$ ($m$ possibilities), every integer will be the same for $\dfrac nm$ sequences (assuming a uniform distribution).

If you obtain a checksum not seen before, you are sure that the sequence is different. But if it matches another checksum, you are stuck. The loss of information is unrecoverable.

---

On another hand, you can generate a huge number of random sequences (much more than a computer could store) before the probability of a hit becomes significant. So it is questionable whether detecting duplicates makes any sense.

Comment: But I am not trying to recover the old series, just prove the new series is not equal to it.  I understand a simple sum would be insufficient proof (simple example is easy), but could a small set of alternative operations be compared and be complete.

Comment: @bliswell: I did not said that you tried to recover the sequences. And my answer holds whatever arithmetic formula you use.